# Which denominations follow "queer theology"?

Tags: exegesis, homosexuality

According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queer_theology), it briefly describes this:

> Queer theology begins with an assumption that gender non-conformity and homosexual desire have always been present in human history, and are present in the Bible. It is a way of unraveling structures and stories that have been oppressive. It is also a way of understanding the Bible as a source of stories about radical love.

It seems to me that this type of theology is strictly limited to academia; however, I may be wrong. Are there any denominations that follow "queer theology", and who are they? I know denominations that are open to LGBT Christians, but they do not seem to be focused on this style of interpretation of the Bible.

Comment: Does this "Queer Theology" then claim that homosexual behavior is justified because it is in the Bible? Or just that it is addressed in the Bible?

Comment: I don't know. I also haven't read any work by a queer theologian. Then again, I haven't read any work by any theologian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Evangelical Lutheran Church in America went through a deliberation process on whether to change its restrictions against non-celibate homosexual pastors, culminating in a vote in 2009.  Some of the documents prepared by the ELCA to argue for this change sound very similar to what you have typed.  Here is one such document, ["Journeying Faithfully Together"](http://www.elca.org/~/media/Files/What%20We%20Believe/Social%20Issues/In%20Process/Human%20Sexuality/Studies/study02.ashx). Here is their summary page on ["Historical Resources"](http://www.elca.org/What-We-Believe/Social-Issues/Social-Statements/JTF-Human-Sexuality/Resources.aspx) on the topic.  Individual congregations went further, some signing on to a [Reconciled in Christ](http://www.reconcilingworks.org/ric/about-reconciling-in-christ) program, which raises similar themes.

Another reference is the book, [Sexual Fulfillment: For Single and Married, Straight and Gay, Young and Old](http://books.google.com/books/about/Sexual_Fulfillment.html?id=quduxRpN4KwC), written by a former bishop, Herbert Chilstrom.  The Amazon.com [summary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SG71OW) includes Chilstrom's comment that for people of all orientations,

> ... sex is a gift from God, intended, in spite of our broken world, for our enjoyment and fulfillment.

Comment: I certainly do not agree with the "approach to scripture" of this movement within the ELCA, FWIW.

Comment: I wonder if the "sex" is within marriage.

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen any major denomination which has not had at least one substantial block that believed in something along the lines of what you call "queer theology." That said, that is most publicly accepted by the Episcopals, who have openly homosexual bishops. It is also a very common opinion among Congregationalists, but that is not surprising as much of their doctrine is dictated on a congregation-by-congregation level. (If you believe Quakers to be Christian, then they too should be considered to accept it on a meeting house-by-meeting house level)

The major divisions of Methodists, Presbyterians, Baptists, and Lutherans take stances opposed to homosexuality in the clergy. This means that while individual congregations can vary, the general rule is that "queer theology" has no official place in those churches.

Roman Catholicism and the various forms of Eastern and Oriental Orthodox groups are decidedly opposed to that view.

Comment: Roman Catholic priests are known to be (or supposed to be) celibate. So, it's not like the Roman Catholic Church just *opposes* openly gay priests in gay relationships.

Comment: @Anonymous The question isn't about the clergy, though the restrictions on the clergy are often a very good indicator of the beliefs of the denomination. In the case of the RCC (and to a lesser extent, the Orthodox), the celibacy requirements make the restrictions on the clergy less useful as an indicator, but it should be noted that no openly practicing homosexual is likely to be ordained deacon any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

The following information is available on the internet it is easy to find LGBTQIA accepting churches in todays modern world. The Bible is not homophobia and God accepts all people. Male, female, intersex and trans.  https://sites.duke.edu/divlib/2022/06/03/reading-list-queer-theology/

Comment: What are these theologians saying about polyamorous "swinging" relationships taking place by mutual consent?

Comment: I also agree that there's no phobia (that being an irrational or unreasonable fear) of homosexuality in the Bible!